# In what methodology can identify a single variable integral that cannot be solve by integration by substitution and integration by parts...?

Tags: calculus

In what methodology can identify a single variable integral that cannot be solve by integration by substitution and integration by parts but only can solve by other methods?

Comment: I cannot understand the question at all.

Comment: @RossMillikan  In another word, is it possible to identify the infinite set/class of all single variable integrals that can only solve by methods other than integration by substitution and integration by parts? is it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sense, if you can integrate by **any** method, then you can integrate by substitution.  (The hard part is finding *which* substitution.)

Suppose we want to do the integral
$$
A = \int f(x)\,dx
\tag{1}$$
where $f$ is a very complicated function.  And suppose it has an integral $F(x)$, which we get by a secret message.  We can easily check that $F'(x) = f(x)$.  But then, make the substitution $u = F(x)$ in (1) ... of course we easily compute $du = F'(x) dx = f(x) dx$, so when we do the substitution we get
$$
A = \int \; du = u+C = F(x) + C
$$
Done by "substitution".

Comment: Err... yes... what an amazing fact...